# write function rand30() which uses rand100() which is uniformly distributed returns 1 to 100

Tags: algorithm

Please try to write function `rand30()` which should return 1 to 30.

You have `rand100()` function.

Comment: The result should be an integer in [1,30]?

Comment: Let me guess... homework?

Comment: If you're going to ask for help with your homework, you need to show us what you've tried, and tell us where you're stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the functions return integers:

```
int r = rand100();
while (r > 90) {
    r = rand100();
}
return 1 + (r - 1) % 30;
```

Where the `%` operator means modulo.

To get a uniform distribution of 30 output numbers when we have uniformly distributed 100 input numbers the best we can do is to map 3 of the input numbers to one output number. The remaining 10 inputs must be discarded.

How often do we call rand100 on average?
1 time in 90%
2 times in 9%
3 times in 0.9%
...

The average is 1.111111

Comment: Possible endless loop... 9/10 points :-)

Comment: @jimpic: the question allows us to assume the `rand100` function is uniformly distributed, so this loop is endless with probability 0.

Comment: I don't think that's a good solution. Making loops for converting between same distribution type, just for scaling, is, well, a bad practice. Also, can you prove that it will be uniformly distibuted?

Comment: @SteveJessop good point, replace "endless" with "time-consuming" ;)

Comment: @dreamzoe: this or something like it is the *only* way to get a uniform distribution. It's time-consuming with small probability, but that is the price you pay for uniformity. At the cost of more code it could be made slightly more efficient in terms of the expected number of calls to `rand100` before it returns. But not much more efficient.

Comment: @jimpic Higher numbers of iterations are exponentially unlikely. So this won't be time consuming, assuming the `rand100` works well.

Comment: @dreamzor I added an explanation to the answer

Comment: It's possible to build slightly more efficient code by not discarding, and instead using the remaining values on the next iteration. But this function is already very efficient in practice.

Comment: The chance of a single iteration resulting in another is 0.1. If the minimum number of acceptable iterations is 5, the chance of that is 0.00001.

Comment: Approximately 0.33% more efficient, I think. If you make two calls without returning, then saving the spare values saves you from making a third call. So with probability 0.01 it's about 33% more efficient, otherwise the saved values gain you nothing. That's assuming that the cost of manipulating the values is negligible compared with the cost of calling `rand100`. If we were building `rand5` on top of `rand9` then the case for accumulating values would be stronger.